# how is it Regular expression Reverse check?

Tags: javascript, php, expression

expression Get string in reverse?
Code:
`%.{1,2}`

aims:
`%E7%DC%9EXA%EE%A5%9E`

Obtain:
`XA`

Answer (score 0):

No reverse. Think about how you anchor the needed reference. Such an expression

```
((%[\da-fA-F]{1,2})*)(.*)((%[\da-fA-F]{1,2}))*
```

Each parenthesis creates a group which is numbered starting with 1.
If you apply to following string:

```
%E7%DC%9EXA%EE%A5%9E
```

You will obtain three groups

```
Group 1: %E7%DC%9E
Group 2: XA
Group 3: %EE%A5%9E
```

Take the Group 2
Test the regular expression online https://regexr.com/